# Woocommerce order export hook not working

Tags: php, wordpress, csv, woocommerce

I have written the bellow code in my functions.php file to change some custom modification on export csv.

```
add_filter('wc_customer_order_csv_export_generated_csv_row','array_to_csv_row',1,10);

function array_to_csv_row($data){
        ob_start();

        $stream = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

        fputcsv( $stream, $data, ',', '"' );

        fclose( $stream );

        return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Now the csv was created as empty file.why?

Comment: Whats the result of var_dump(ob_get_clean()); die; ?

Comment: Getting string(0) ""

Comment: $a = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); var_dump($a); die; 

Is this also empty? (Do it after fclose)

Comment: Also try to set the filter priority (last argument) to 100 instead of 10.

Comment: Tried above two methods,still getting string(0) ""

Comment: what is the content of $data?